# Slick Mtable.getTables select database name

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

My Scala/Play DB URL config looks like this:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost"
```

I don't(can't) select the database, because I use multiple databases.

I have a method that retrieves data from database table in form of a map of column name and value pairs:

```
def getSession(id: String, db: String): Map[String, Any] = DB.withSession {

    val columns = MTable.getTables(None, None, None, None).list.filter(_.name.name == "myTable").head.getColumns.list.map(_.column) 
    val result = sql"""SELECT * FROM #$db.myTable WHERE id=$id""".as[List[Any]].firstOption.map(columns zip _ toMap).get

}
```

`MTable.getTables` doesn't seem to work in this occasion, because I assume it expects `DB.withSession` to have a database selected, which is not the case. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define multiple databases in Play if you want to use multiple databases, eg:

```
db.database1.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database1"
db.database2.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database2"
db.database3.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/database3"
```

Then, you'll have to run the query on each different database, and merge the results, eg:

```
DB("database1").withSession { ... } ++ DB("database2").withSession { ... }
```

etc...